# npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 12842

Tags: angular, npm

Every time I try installing any package or even if I try doing `npm install` I keep getting this error. I have no idea why I am getting the error. I am totally new to Angular 4, it's only been a week, so any any leads will be appreciated. I am using node -v 8.8.1 and @angular/cli 1.4.9.

This is my package.json.

```
{
    "name": "events-across", 
    "version": "0.0.0", 
    "license": "MIT", 
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng", 
        "start": "ng serve", 
        "build": "ng build", 
        "test": "ng test", 
        "lint": "ng lint", 
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    }, 
    "private": true, 
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/common": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/core": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/http": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/router": "^4.2.4", 
        "angular-font-awesome": "^2.3.7", 
        "angular4-carousel": "^3.1.8", 
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta", 
        "core-js": "^2.4.1", 
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0", 
        "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21", 
        "rxjs": "^5.4.2", 
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    }, 
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.4.9", 
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4", 
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4", 
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53", 
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2", 
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60", 
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0", 
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2", 
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0", 
        "karma": "~1.7.0", 
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1", 
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1", 
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1", 
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0", 
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2", 
        "protractor": "~5.1.2", 
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0", 
        "tslint": "~5.7.0", 
        "typescript": "~2.3.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try to remove package.lock file

Possible issue [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17340)

Comment: Yes thank you, i used rm package-lock.json and it did the trick.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this: I had the same problem, and it was caused by a bad merge conflict resolution in `package-lock.json`. (Git had added `<<<<<<< HEAD ... ======= ... >>>>>>> master` lines to the file.) But it was very annoying that the error message didn't say anything about `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 19):

It's because of a `package-lock.json` merge conflict.

Delete the file, delete `node_modules`, and run `npm install` to solve the problem:

```sh
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the package-lock.json didn't work for me. The issue was an extra comma in my package.json file.

Try copying your json file into [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com). It will give you more information to show you if the issue you're having is truly a syntax error.

Checkout this article https://dev.to/redslug/7-solutions-to-ejsonparse-or-unexpected-token-npm-install-error-20nh if none of the answers here help. It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

For me , removing package.lock did not work

Try the following steps

1- set registry to `https://registry.npmjs.org/`. `http` did not work and had to change it to `https`

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

2- I am behind a corporate firewall so i had to setup my proxy and https-proxy accordingly in the format - `http://yourproxyurl:port`

```
npm config set proxy http://someproxyurl.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://someproxyurl.com:8080
```

3 - Set `ssl` to `false`

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

These steps worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command "npm cache verify" if removing package.lock does not work

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, my issue was that we switched from using nexus to artifactory. You can find that out by using
        npm config get registry
which in my case printed out the URL to our old nexus repository. Then use
        npm config set registry https://artifactory.your-company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
and that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the package-lock.json and run `npm i` again, it works for me

v8.1.4

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting `package.lock` was not enough. My IDE always said this error:

> Unexpected token <

So what I did:

1. Removed package.lock file
2. In IDE: `npm cache verify`
3. I write **in the plain [command-line interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) , NOT in IDE** :

   ```
   npm install @angular/http
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of error try with below steps:

- Delete package-lock.json
- Run npm install

The above solution worked correctly for me. Hope will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `package-lock.json`. I just run the `rm package-lock.json` and It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened, because I have added an entry in the script section of `package.json` file. Check your `pachage.json` file if you already added any item to the script section and try to remove or fix it.
Also check if there is no any kamma at the end of object right before `}` close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my `package.json` there were some dependencies to external/customer libraries. To make it possible to download`.npmrc` must be configured according to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration so npm knows where to look for packages and how to authenticate in external registry.

If that is wrong it tries to download dependencies wrongly and why expecting to have JSON file it gets HTML error page form the server like that:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!doctype html><html...'`

Answer (score -1):

If above suggestions didn't solve the issue, check your package.json file. Make sure there is no syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

For me,

removing the package-lock.json and package.json files, unstaging them, and discarding the changes worked. After this, I restored these from VSCode. After that, npm install worked fine!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was trying to create react native app with npx and npm and for anyone experiencing this error, just uninstall and install node. It worked for me.